# how to solve error:expected identifier or '(' in C language

Tags: c, cs50

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void);
{
   int i;

    do

    { 
         i=get_int("Height:");
         printf("Height:%i./n")
    }
    while(i>0 && i<9);


    for(int j=1;j<9;j++)
    {
        for(int z=int i-1;z<9;z++)
        {
            printf("../n");
        }
        printf("#./n");
    }
```

i have been trying to solve for a long time but it is not working. the error it is showing is:

```
mario.c:5:1: error: expected identifier or '('
{
^
1 error generated.
```

can anyone please tell my mistake

i am supposed to form the blocks of mario

Comment: you miss a `;` here `printf("Height:%i./n")`

Comment: And you miss a `}` in the end

Comment: I was writing an answer, but I felt guilty. Your error is here `int main(void);`: that semicolon is not required in main function _definition_. (in ANY function definition)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you added a `;` after main declaration and you missed one after this `printf` `printf("Height:%i./n")`

this `;` should be removed `int main(void);`

and  add one `}` at the end of main.

also you has to remove second `int` here `for(int z=int i-1;z<9;z++)` this should be `for(int z=i-1;z<9;z++)`.

Comment: @RudraJadav  feel free,there is no need for thanks, but if this answer was helpful accept the answer.